# LaTeX in comments

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing a comment containing formulae will mangle the formulae](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/459/editing-a-comment-containing-formulae-will-mangle-the-formulae)

Ìs it by design that LaTeX gets mangled when one edits a comment? It used to work correctly, IIRC...

(This is probably a duplicate subject on meta.MSE, but the other one got closed as completed)

Comment: The dupe isn't closed as completed: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/459/editing-a-comment-containing-formulae-will-mangle-the-formulae